# How to get a Coordinates of a 3D Object in Android

Tags: android, 3d

How is it possible to click on an area of a 3D Model (.obj-File) for example a cube, where you can get different Events of the six sides. For Example the orange area of the picture gives me a value of an Integer. The Cube can be rotated 360°.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this cube is made of triangles. You can simply ray cast the scene and check Ray/Triangle intersection for every face triangle. The ray cast function will return the triangle index and the 3D intersection point, once you have this info you can do what you want. You need to look for Unproject and ray/triangle intersection.

Comment: thank you for your answer. what could be used for this task? Is it possible to do that with for example min3d or jPCT?

Comment: I didn't use any of those libraries. But any decent 3D library should have some kind of ray casting.

Comment: @csnewb check this http://www.gamedev.net/topic/563606-basic-raycasting-tutorials/

Comment: ty, i have got one more question: is it possible to mark (for example to red) the selected side's surface by clicking on it, only by programming(not by changing something on the .obj file itself)?

Comment: Yes, when rendering the obj, you need to render the selected faces on a separate draw call. Or at this is the way that I can think of at the moment.